# Regexp match any character except a particular string

Tags: php, xml, regex

I am using the regexp,

```
/(\<\s*?string(-array)?\s*?.*?\s*?\>\s*?)(.*)(\s*?\<\/string(-array)?\>)/
```

... to match all content between  or  tags of the form:

```
<string-array name="saveArray">
  <item>Téléphone</item>
  <item>Carte mémoires</item>
</string-array>
```

Problem is, I'm only able to match the contents of 'string' tags or arrays containing one item. When I replace the dot from the captured group in the middle with [^s], I get the content I want, but this solution would fail to match any content containing 's'. I tried a negative look-behind for 'str' immediately preceding the content ('item-matching') group, and it is giving me the same results.

Any help would be great!

Comment: you want to parse xml? would this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php  help you?

Comment: can you shortly explain(better with examples) what you got as input, and what you want in matched result?

Comment: FYI, `<`, `>` and `/` have no special meaning in regexes and do not need to be escaped.  `/` is special *in this case* because you used it as the regex delimiter, but PHP allows you to choose a different delimiter--popular choices are `~`, `#`, or `%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***really*** should not parse xml using regexps.

That said, I think the thing that's messing you up might be that "`.`" (in many regexp engines, with default flags) matches any character *except* a newline..  So your `.*` will not match more than one line.  Try replacing "`.*`" with "`[\w\W]*`", or adding a regexp flag that says that "`.`" should match all characters.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) to parse XML. The XML may change or not match your regex in edge cases - so it's best to just use an XML parser.

```
<?php
$xml '<string-array name="saveArray">'
. '<item>Téléphone</item>'
. '<item>Carte mémoires</item>'
. '</string-array>';

$items = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm required to use Regex.

Comment: "required to use Regex"...? How are you required to use it?

Comment: For the purposes of this project, I have to use regex. Kind of reinventing the wheel here, I know, but it's necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said do **not** use regex to parse xml/html.

In any case this should work :

```
if ($subject =~ m!<(string-array)[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>!si) {
    print $2, "\n";
}
```

Comment: What's with the `*` in `(string-array*)`?  Did you mean `(string-array\b)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what * you're talking about, Alan Moore. Nothing follows either "string(-array)?"